# Symbol font AGA Arabesque works in Chrome, not in FF and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, fonts

I am trying to use `AGA Arabesque` font (downloaded from [here](http://www.fontspace.com/mak-alagha/aga-arabesque)), with this CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AGA Arabesque';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('//example.com/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/140705120824ARABSQ.eot');
    src: local('AGA Arabesque'), url('//example.com/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/140705120824ARABSQ.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('//example.com/wp-content/uploads/useanyfont/140705120824ARABSQ.woff') format('woff');
}
```

I am able to use the font properly in Chrome. In the latest Firefox and IE, all I see is an English letter in place of the desired symbol.

In Chrome:

[image]

In Firefox:

[image]

What could be going wrong? Is there a way I could use base64 encoding to try and get around this issue?

EDIT: Other fonts, used this way, work correctly on all three major browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted the font to WOFF, and I found that all glyphs got mapped into the Unicode Private Use Area, in the U+F000 block. I don't know if this is a bug in the conversion tools or in the font. But given that this font is quite old (it's dated 1994, so it's from the Windows 3.1 era), it's likely that it doesn't comply with current standards.

I see two options to get this font working:

1. Get a font editor and fix the character assignment.
2. Use entity references to access the glyphs. Not very convenient, but possible: look up the hex code for your character [in an ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart), add `F0` in front of it, and use that code in an entity reference. E.g. `[` has hex code `5B`, so use entity refrence `&#xF05B;`. ([Sample page download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wirfbfpd7ute331/arabesque.zip))

This works in Firefox and Chrome for me. I don't have a Windows system handy to test Internet Explorer and the EOT format, but I suspect the situation there will be identical.

Comment: Which font editor would you recommend? I'll be using one for the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I've got no experience with font editing tools. I'm just a programmers who has encountered broken fonts once or twice before.

Comment: I get a bunch of warnings when I open the TTF file in FontForge, like:
"The glyph named I is mapped to U+F049. But its name indicates it should be mapped to U+0049".

So I need to change all this, you mean?

Comment: As I said, I have no experience with font editors :) I've faced a similar situation before but I went with the second option (using entity references).

Comment: UPDATE: I used BirdFont to create a new font with the required glyphs mapped into the U+0000 block. Now, the font works in Chrome, IE and Firefox, just as I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your WebFont is too large to be considered for rending. During testing even Chrome decided to render with Times New Roman.

If you're only using a set of characters from the font, consider creating a new font with only those characters.

---

Encoding the font using base64 will on narrow your audience, since not all browser support it. Interestingly enough the webfonts are loaded without an error, the browser simply refuse to render them, even the font preview in Chrome is just plain Times New Roman.

---

Also the link you posted doesn't link to a web font, just to a regular desktop font.

Comment: You can use several tools to create a new font. Easiest way is using SVG glyphs and converting them to the required web fonts. Here is a tutorial that might help with that: http://www.intridea.com/blog/2012/4/24/symbol-font